# How can I get the Player score of a given leaderboard in Apple Game Center from unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-center

I would like to know how I can get the int value of the local player scores on a given Apple Game Center (apple Gamekit plugin) leaderboard from Unity (c#). I'm new with that API, and I can't find a specific method.